# Adding and displaying data from a locally stored GeoJSON file using MapBox

Tags: java, android, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-android

I'm attempting to add markers to a map from a GeoJSON File that has been added to the "asset" folder.

I've attempted to follow [the documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/data-driven-styling/) however have been unable to get the expected result since the markers are no where to be found when running the app.

***My Attempt:***

```
public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;

    mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS,
            new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                @Override
                public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                    enableLocationComponent(style);
                    GeoJsonSource source = null;
                    try {
                        source = new GeoJsonSource("geojson-source", new URI("asset://markerdata.geojson"));
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    style.addSource(source);

                    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.marker);
                    style.addImage("marker", icon);


                    SymbolLayer symbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("layer-id", "source-id"); // ?
                    symbolLayer.setProperties(PropertyFactory.iconImage("marker"));

                    style.addLayer(symbolLayer);

                }
            });

}
```

I have noticed that `SymbolLayer` expects a `layer-id` and `source-id` however fail to understand what these are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The markers should appear if you put the `GeoJsonSource` id as the `SymbolLayer` source id:

```
SymbolLayer symbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("layer-id", "geojson-source");
```

The layer id is an identifier for the layer, the source id is the id of the data source to display, in your case it's "geojson-source".